# Validate float value in KeyPress event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, keypress

I am trying to implement a function to validate a `float` value when user types something in a `TextBox` control using `KeyPress` event.

**This is what I've tried:**

```
private void ValidateFloat(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int b;

    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back ||
        e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Delete ||
        e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Left ||
        e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Right ||
        int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out b))
    {
        TextBox obj = sender as TextBox;
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && obj.Text.IndexOf('.') > 0)
            e.Handled = true;
        else
            e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
        e.Handled = true;
}

private void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    this.ValidateFloat(sender, e);
}
```

But for some reason this seems to work but not at all, please check below description...

---

**First case:** User types a numeric value like **20.5**

**Observations:**

There is already a dot in the number as the decimal separator. So, when trying to press the dot key again to put another one, validation works fine.

---

**Second case:** User types a value like **..20.5**

**Observations:**

The first digit can't be a dot in a numeric value. Also, there is more than one dot and validation doesn't work fine.

---

So, my question is...

**How can I fix the above code in order to get a really good validation of a `float` value?** (without "bugs").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if (e.KeyChar=='.' && (obj.Text.IndexOf('.')>0 || obj.Text.Length==0))
```

to catch the 'leading decimal'.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply try to parse textbox's text (you can provide number style and format if needed)?

```
private void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;
    float value;
    if (float.TryParse(textbox.Text, out value))
        // input is valid
}
```

I believe this validation of float values do not have bugs.